# Replaying merged streams individually

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

I have an ObservableTransformer composed out of a few sub-streams merged together as shown in the example below.

```java
ObservableTransformer<Action, Result> actionsToResults =
        actions -> actions.publish(shared ->
                Observable.merge(
                        Observable.merge(
                                shared.ofType(SendMessageAction.class).compose(sendMessageTransformer),
                                shared.ofType(CheckMessageInputAction.class).compose(checkIfEmptyTransformer)),
                        model.messagesObservable
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                )).replay(1).autoConnect();

//      ╔════╗
//   ╔══╣    ╠══╗
// ══╣  ╚════╝  ╠══(replay)>
//   ╚══════════╝
```

I'm replaying the last element emitted, what I would like however is to replay the streams individually. Like this:

```java
//      ╔════╗
//   ╔══╣    ╠═(replay)═╗
// ══╣  ╚════╝          ╠══>
//   ╚═════════(replay)═╝
```

So that when I subscribe to the whole stream, it emits the last elements of both of these inner streams. Can this be done?

EDIT: In an effort to make my problems clearer, I'm going to expand on where I think the problem lies.

I want the whole stream to be a connectable observable. This is important because it lives inside a headless fragment and is not supposed to re-trigger all its calls on rotation. At the same time I want to replay those streams individually. Moving `.replay(1).autoConnect()` inside the outer merge wouldn't work. The whole stream would be recreated at each new subscription. Adding a custom operator in the outer merge, something like:

```java
private ObservableTransformer<Action, Result> actionsToResults =
            actions -> actions.publish(shared -> Observable.merge(Observable.merge(
                    shared.ofType(SendMessageAction.class).compose(sendMessageTransformer),
                    shared.ofType(CheckMessageInputAction.class).compose(checkIfEmptyTransformer)).lift(new ReplayLastOperator<Result>())
                    model.messagesObservable.lift(new ReplayLastOperator<>()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            ));
```

Where `ReplayLastOperator<Result>()` replays the last element on each new subscription is equivalent to moving the `replay(1).autoConnect()`, the whole stream is recreated at each new subscription. So there is nothing to replay. The above solution with a `.publish().autoConnect()` at the end, will only subscribe to the inner streams once, so I loose the ability to detect new subscriptions upstream, therefor the replay also doesn't work.

I have run out of ideas.

Comment: Certainly it can be done. To recap, then. original stream looks like `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, while merged stream looks like `1, 11, 2, 3, 33, 4, 5`. When you subscribe to the stream you want the last item from each stream: `33, 5`?

Comment: @BobDalgleish Yes. That's what I want.

Comment: @BobDalgleish If you find some time, could you please give me some suggestions on how to solve this?

Comment: Your diagram does not match your code. It looks like you have two incoming streams, the original `actions` and also `model.messagesObservable`. `actions` is split into two streams and then merged. Can you clarify?

Comment: @BobDalgleish You are of course correct. I didn't have that part ready yet, in the future `model.messagesObservable` would be dependent on incoming actions, right now it just spits out dummy data. I split the streams up so I can implement that separate caching for responses to different actions.

Comment: I strongly suggest you create a much simpler model and test it out before trying with the operators and data structures you are using. For instance, create an observable stream of integers; branch 1 filters even integers and multiplies by 16, branch 2 filters odd integers and multiplies by 11. Then your test stream would look like: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 for input and 11, 1, 16, 2, 33, 3, 48, 4, 55, 5 for output, and making a new subscription would immediately emit 55, 5.

Comment: Also, you using a `lift()` operator when all you want is `.replay(1)`.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Solved it for my purposes. If you find the time please review my answer. You seem to have the experience. I would hate to spread a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, for my particular case. I'm going to add a little bit of extra info, for you to see if it applies to your situation.

In my case all the streams I want to replay return objects of a different type, sealed by an abstract class. So my solution to this problem was to implement my own `ObservableTransoformer`, named `ReplayLastByClassType`, which cashes the last elements received by type in a map. You apply it simply by calling `.compose(ReplayLastByClassType.<SealingClass>instance()`, or just `ReplayLastByClassType.instance()`.

The transformer re-emits the cashed values in on subscribe. Afterwards it continues to pass the elements at consecutive `onNext` calls.

- **WARNING 1. The order of elements returned in onSubscribe is not necessarily preserved.** (This was not necessary in my case).
- **WARNING 2. The upstream observable will not be unsubscribed from even if all subscribers of the transformed observable unsubscribe!!!** This is by design.

This approach could also work for you, even if the streams you want to replay return objects of identical type. You would have to wrap the results into separate helper classes to force the separation by class.

Finally the bespoke `ObservableTransformer`, happy copy pasting :)

```
public final class ReplayLastByClassType<T> implements ObservableTransformer<T, T> {

    private static final ReplayLastByClassType<Object> INSTANCE = new ReplayLastByClassType<>();

    /** The singleton instance of this transformer **/
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> ReplayLastByClassType<T> instance() {
        return (ReplayLastByClassType<T>) INSTANCE;
    }

    private ReplayLastByClassType() {
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<T> apply(Observable<T> upstream) {
        LastSeen<T> lastSeen = new LastSeen<>();
        return new LastSeenObservable<>(upstream.doOnNext(lastSeen).publish().autoConnect(), lastSeen);
    }

    static final class LastSeen<T> implements Consumer<T> {
        ConcurrentHashMap<Class, T> values = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        @Override public void accept(T latest) {
            values.put(latest.getClass(), latest);
        }
    }

    static final class LastSeenObservable<T> extends Observable<T> {
        private final Observable<T> upstream;
        private final LastSeen<T> lastSeen;

        LastSeenObservable(Observable<T> upstream, LastSeen<T> lastSeen) {
            this.upstream = upstream;
            this.lastSeen = lastSeen;
        }

        @Override
        protected void subscribeActual(Observer<? super T> observer) {
            upstream.subscribe(new LastSeenObserver<T>(observer, lastSeen));
        }
    }

    static final class LastSeenObserver<T> implements Observer<T> {
        private final Observer<? super T> downstream;
        private final LastSeen<T> lastSeen;

        LastSeenObserver(Observer<? super T> downstream, LastSeen<T> lastSeen) {
            this.downstream = downstream;
            this.lastSeen = lastSeen;
        }

        @Override public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            downstream.onSubscribe(d);

            Map<Class, T> values = lastSeen.values;
            for (T t: values.values()) {
                downstream.onNext(t);
            }
        }

        @Override public void onNext(T value) {
            downstream.onNext(value);
        }

        @Override public void onComplete() {
            downstream.onComplete();
        }

        @Override public void onError(Throwable e) {
            downstream.onError(e);
        }
    }
}
```

PS: If you see any errors in the code please correct me in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You can create a custom operator that caches the last item it saw.

Then when an onComplete is received from upstream it re-emits the last item it saw before emitting onComplete itself.  A generic form of that operator would look like the following:

```
public class ReplayLast <T>  implements ObservableOperator<T, T> {
@Override
public Observer<? super T> apply(@NonNull final Observer<? super T> observer) throws Exception {
    return new Observer<T>(){

        Disposable disposable;
        T lastItem;  // cache for last item

        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            disposable = d;
            observer.onSubscribe(d);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(@NonNull T t) {
            lastItem = t;  // cache each item from up stream
            observer.onNext(t); // emit as usual
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            observer.onError(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            if(lastItem != null){
                // use the cache to emit the item again before signaling the complete downstream
                observer.onNext(lastItem);
            }
            observer.onComplete();
        }
    };
}
```

Then it's just a matter of using it in the appropriate places.  Should be something like the following:

```
ObservableTransformer<Action, Result> actionsToResults =
        actions -> actions.publish(shared ->
                Observable.merge(
                        Observable.merge(
                                shared.ofType(SendMessageAction.class).compose(sendMessageTransformer),
                                shared.ofType(CheckMessageInputAction.class).compose(checkIfEmptyTransformer)).lift(new ReplayLast()),
                        model.messagesObservable.lift(new ReplayLast())
                                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                )).autoConnect();
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I couldn't get back to you during the weekend. I should have probably been more specific about what the code above does. When I wrote "I'm replaying the last element emitted" I meant on each new subscription, not when the stream is completed. But I don't think simply moving the code to onSubcribe is an option. Because in order for the caching of the last element to work I need it to be a connectable observable, and if I understand correctly the onSubscribe would in this case only be called once. PS: You forgot a publish before `.autoConnect()`

Comment: I know you are probably busy, but will you take another shot at this?